# How to avoid repetition of carousel items in react-slick

Tags: reactjs, react-slick

I'm using react-slick. I want to show four items at a time. I'm showing data dynamically.

If I have single item in carousel, it's repeating to fill the place of four items.

This is my code:

```
const settings = {
    dots: false,
    infinite: true,
    speed: 500,
    slidesToShow: 4,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
};

<Slider {...settings}>
  //mapping data
</Slider>
```

Thank you

Comment: I think that is happening because you have `infinite` set to true. Try setting it to false and check.

Comment: Yes. It's working. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It repeats to fill all the 4 places since `infinite` is provided as `true`. So it try to find four items, but ends up finding the same item again and again. To get your desired behaviour(that is it scrolls infinitely in both directions), i suggest you set the `slidesToShow` dynamically.

Assuming you have your `mapping data` in `list`, you can set the number of `slidesToShow` dynamically.

```
const settings = {
 dots: false,
 infinite: true,
 speed: 500,
 slidesToShow: list.length > 4 ? 4 : list.length,
 slidesToScroll: 1,
};

<Slider {...settings}>
  //mapping data
</Slider>
```

Answer (score 1):

infinte : items.length >3;

let settings = {
slidesToShow: 3,
arrows: false,
infinite: megaProjects.length > 3,
slidesToScroll: 3,
autoplay: true,
autoplaySpeed: 8000,
lazyLoad: true,
}

Answer (score 0):

**I am getting the same issue when I use react slick I got duplicate slide but then I import the style file after that my issue is resolve **

```js
  import "slick-carousel/slick/slick.css"; 
   import "slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.css";
```